# Using Google Calendar as a Webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, google-calendar-api, apex-code

I want to create events in Google Calendar by using a webservice not a the client library.  Does anyone know how to do this?  If you can show me sample for Adding, Updating and Deleting that would be greatly appreciated.

If you are wondering why not use the native Client Library like .Net well I will not use it in .Net but I will using it as an APEX trigger in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a solution and it is wel documented on the DeveloperForce website.

Here is the link http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Google_Calendar_API